# Retrieve the list of network printers

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, permissions

I'm creating a chrome extension and I need to retrieve the list of network printers via this extension.

print ... -> destinations (combos)

is it possible through a javascript function and without any event? which API should I use?

Comment: maybe https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider

Comment: Thanks for the reply. PrinterProvider is based on events, I need to recover them regardless of the operations performed